# Place horizontal line in middle between two divs

Tags: html, css

i have the following HTML/CSS/JS:

```
<div id="blockcart-wrapper">
  <div class="blockcart cart-preview">
    <div class="header">
      <a rel="nofollow" href="#">
        <img class="cart-icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/20x20" onclick="toggleClass()">

      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="body" id="shopping-cart-body">
      <div class="close"><a href="" onclick="toggleClass()">X</a></div>
      <ul>
      </ul>
      <div class="shopping-cart-header">CART</div>
      <div class="products-container">
        <div class="product">
          <span class="prodcut-image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x100"></span>
          <div class="product-details">
            <div class="name-header">This is a very long test name</div>
            <div class="product-quantity-details">
              <span class="quantity">QTY</span>
              <span class="color-circle"></span>
              <span class="color">COLOR</span>
            </div>
            <div class="price-open">
              <span class="product-price">XX.XX</span>
              <span class="product-link"><a href="#">open</a></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="checkout">
        <div class="taxes">
          <span class="label">Taxes</span>
          <span class="value">0</span>
          <hr>
        </div>
        <div class="cart-total">
          <span class="label">Total</span>
          <span class="value">0</span>
        </div>
        <button><a href="#">Checkout</a></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.cart-preview {
float: right;
position: relative;
}

.cart-preview a,
.cart-preview a:hover,
.cart-preview a:visited {
text-decoration: none;
color: inherit;
}

.cart-preview .header {
display: block;
font-weight: bold;
border: 1px solid #808080;
padding: 5px;
cursor: pointer;
background-color: #fff;
}

.cart-preview .body {
visibility: visible;
position: fixed;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
width: 400px;
z-index: 101;
background-color: #fff;
transition: right 1s linear;
right: -400px;
}

.cart-preview .body.open {
visibility: visible;
transition: right 1s linear;
right: 0px;
}

.cart-preview .body .shopping-cart-body {
font-family: 'IBMPlexSerif';
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}

.cart-preview .body .close{
margin-top: 20px;
margin-left: 20px;
font-size: 30px;
float: left;
}
.cart-preview .body .shopping-cart-header{
font-family: 'IBMPlexSans';
font-size: 45px;
margin-top: 40px;
text-align: center;
}
.cart-preview .body .products-container {
position: relative;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
margin-top: 15px;
overflow: auto;
}

.product {
display: flex;
}

.product>div {
width: 50%;
}

.product .prodcut-image {
margin-right: 10px;
}

.product img {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}

.cart-preview .body .products-container>.product-image {
position: absolute;
width: 50%;
left: 0;
}

.cart-preview .body .products-container>.product-details {
position: absolute;
width: 50%;
float: left;
}


.cart-preview .body .products-container .color-circle:before {
content: ' \25CF';
font-size: 30px;
}

.cart-preview .body .checkout {
position: absolute;
top: 80%;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background: white;
}

.product-quantity-details .quantity{
float: left;
text-align: center;
border: 2px solid black;
margin-right: 10px;
background: white;
width: 36px;
height: 36px;
font-size: 15px;
line-height: 33px;
color: black;
}

.cart-preview .product{
margin-top: 10px;
}

.product-quantity-details .quantity:after{
content: 'x'
}
.price-open .product-price:after{
  content: '€';
}
.cart-preview .body .checkout>button {
position: absolute;
background: black;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
border: none;
color: white;
top: 13%;
line-height: 14px;
bottom: 50px;
height: 40px;
width: 205px;
left: 25%;
}

.checkout .taxes{
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
top: 5%;
}

.checkout .cart-total{
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
top: 10%;
float: left;
}

.cart-total .value {
margin-right: 20px;
float: right;
}
.cart-total .value:after {
content:'€'
}

.cart-total .label {
margin-left: 20px;
float: left;
}


.taxes .value {
margin-right: 20px;
float: right;
}

.taxes .label {
margin-left: 20px;
float: left;
}

.taxes>hr{
margin-top: 30px;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-right: 20px;
border-color: black;
}

.product-quantity-details{
align-items: center;
display: inline-flex;
}
.product-details{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: flex-start
}
```

and JavaScript:

```
function toggleClass() {
  document.getElementById('shopping-cart-body').classList.toggle('open');
}
```

Now I want to achieve to have the `<hr>` within the div with the class checkout to be placed always at the middle of the space between the taxes and the total sum.
How can I achieve this? I tried height: 50% and top: 50%.
I summed this up in a codepen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EeyEPg

Update:
I just learned how to achieve the effect with a div, so i need to align this new div between the two other divs, so I updated the codepen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use `border-bottom` instead of an `<hr>` tag, like the example:

https://codepen.io/RACCH/pen/gdMeGQ

```js
function toggleClass() {
  document.getElementById('shopping-cart-body').classList.toggle('open');
}
```

```css
.cart-preview {
float: right;
position: relative;
}

.cart-preview a,
.cart-preview a:hover,
.cart-preview a:visited {
text-decoration: none;
color: inherit;
}

.cart-preview .header {
display: block;
font-weight: bold;
border: 1px solid #808080;
padding: 5px;
cursor: pointer;
background-color: #fff;
}

.cart-preview .body {
visibility: visible;
position: fixed;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
width: 400px;
z-index: 101;
background-color: #fff;
transition: right 1s linear;
right: -400px;
}

.cart-preview .body.open {
visibility: visible;
transition: right 1s linear;
right: 0px;
}

.cart-preview .body .shopping-cart-body {
font-family: 'IBMPlexSerif';
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}

.cart-preview .body .close{
margin-top: 20px;
margin-left: 20px;
font-size: 30px;
float: left;
}
.cart-preview .body .shopping-cart-header{
font-family: 'IBMPlexSans';
font-size: 45px;
margin-top: 40px;
text-align: center;
}
.cart-preview .body .products-container {
position: relative;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
margin-top: 15px;
overflow: auto;
}

.product {
display: flex;
}

.product>div {
width: 50%;
}

.product .prodcut-image {
margin-right: 10px;
}

.product img {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}

.cart-preview .body .products-container>.product-image {
position: absolute;
width: 50%;
left: 0;
}

.cart-preview .body .products-container>.product-details {
position: absolute;
width: 50%;
float: left;
}


.cart-preview .body .products-container .color-circle:before {
content: ' \25CF';
font-size: 30px;
}

.cart-preview .body .checkout {
position: absolute;
top: 80%;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background: white;
}

.product-quantity-details .quantity{
float: left;
text-align: center;
border: 2px solid black;
margin-right: 10px;
background: white;
width: 36px;
height: 36px;
font-size: 15px;
line-height: 33px;
color: black;
}

.cart-preview .product{
margin-top: 10px;
}

.product-quantity-details .quantity:after{
content: 'x'
}
.price-open .product-price:after{
  content: '€';
}
.cart-preview .body .checkout>button {
position: absolute;
background: black;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
border: none;
color: white;
top: 13%;
line-height: 14px;
bottom: 50px;
height: 40px;
width: 205px;
left: 25%;
}

.checkout .taxes{
position: absolute;
/* width: 100%; */
top: 5%;
}

.checkout .cart-total{
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
top: 10%;
float: left;
}

.cart-total .value {
margin-right: 20px;
float: right;
}
.cart-total .value:after {
content:'€'
}

.cart-total .label {
margin-left: 20px;
float: left;
}


.taxes .value {
/* margin-right: 20px; */
float: right;
}

.taxes .label {
/* margin-left: 20px; */
float: left;
}

.taxes>hr{
margin-top: 30px;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-right: 20px;
border-color: black;
}

.taxes {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0px 22px;
    width: calc(100% - 48px);
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.product-quantity-details{
align-items: center;
display: inline-flex;
}
.product-details{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: flex-start
}
```

```html
<div id="blockcart-wrapper">
  <div class="blockcart cart-preview">
    <div class="header">
      <a rel="nofollow" href="#">
        <img class="cart-icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/20x20" onclick="toggleClass()">

      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="body" id="shopping-cart-body">
      <div class="close"><a href="" onclick="toggleClass()">X</a></div>
      <ul>
      </ul>
      <div class="shopping-cart-header">CART</div>
      <div class="products-container">
        <div class="product">
          <span class="prodcut-image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x100"></span>
          <div class="product-details">
            <div class="name-header">This is a very long test name</div>
            <div class="product-quantity-details">
              <span class="quantity">QTY</span>
              <span class="color-circle"></span>
              <span class="color">COLOR</span>
            </div>
            <div class="price-open">
              <span class="product-price">XX.XX</span>
              <span class="product-link"><a href="#">open</a></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="checkout">
        <div class="taxes">
          <span class="label">Taxes</span>
          <span class="value">0</span>
          
        </div>
        <div class="cart-total">
          <span class="label">Total</span>
          <span class="value">0</span>
        </div>
        <button><a href="#">Checkout</a></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but with a border-bottom, i cant place it in the middle between the two other divs:/

Answer (score 4):

The `<hr>` tag has a different meaning in HTML5 than previous versions of HTML. [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hr.asp) has a very good description of this, but basically it used to be a visual element while now it's a structural element. It symbolizes a thematic break between two different sections of content.

Based on your question, I'm assuming you're trying to achieve the visual effect. You don't need the `<hr>` tag for this at all! Just use border-bottom like so:

```
div {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```